# JavaScript returning wrong IE version

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, version

I have a small JavaScript function that is supposed to return the IE version.

Problem is, when I publish and view the site this function is returning 7.

I am viewing the site with IE 8.0.7600.16385.

What's going on?

```
function getIEVersionNumber() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var MSIEOffset = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (MSIEOffset == -1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return parseFloat(ua.substring(MSIEOffset + 5, ua.indexOf(";", MSIEOffset)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `alert(navigator.userAgent)` to see what the page is getting.

Comment: @rockerest lol awesome +1 for comment. I really think that might be it. MSIE is constantly screwing with the version in my experience.

Comment: What does `navigator.userAgent` contain?

Comment: When I run IE9 in compatibility mode and alert `navigator.userAgent` it reports IE 8.  **gotta** be compatibility mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your browser is running in IE 7 compatible mode?

Comment: If you haven't declared a [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) it will default to "quirks" or compatibility mode.  Generally there will be a little "broken page" icon to the right of the URL bar.

Comment: there is a button next to the location bar

Comment: alert(document.documentMode) will return the parser version currently running, as set by you, or by the user, or by some third party.